# Managing e-mail addresses

Tags: support, login

[image: Screenshot]

I have stopped using the e-mail address in red. So I want my entire Stack Exchange life to move to the address in blue.

If I click "remove" next to the red one, will the blue one be promoted to my primary (only) e-mail address, with the ability to change the password, etc.? It isn't clear. I don't want to find myself locked out of an orphaned account. Most other sites that work with multiple addresses have an explicit way to make a different address become the primary one.

Comment: Nick, do you **really really** want two of your e-mail addresses made public? Literally *everyone* could look at them...

Comment: I really don't mind. I'm in academia and it's quite common to make one's address publicly visible. I've been using e-mail since 1979 and not much has gone seriously wrong yet.

Comment: Its worth remembering, those are openids that *happen* to have the same name as an email address. You can have openids without one (I was mucking with running my own), or to use an email address that's unrelated using shog's method

Answer (score 6):

There's no "primary" login - you can use any login, any time. If you no longer want one, remove it and you'll still be able to use the rest.

Note that logins are different (though not *entirely* separate) from email addresses: if you remove a given email from your credentials but still have it configured as your contact email, you'll still get emails sent there. To change *that*, click [edit email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) on the left and you'll see one or more fields that can be edited (some sites - by which I mean Stack Overflow - can have more'n one email address listed on that page for various and sundry purposes).

Note finally that there are or were other places where email addresses could be set at various points in the past. Those *should* all be consolidated under email settings now, but we may have forgotten some (lookin' at you, [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/current)). If you're still getting emails on your old address after removing it from the Logins and Email Settings pages, there should be a link in the footer of said emails that takes you to the location where those too can be changed. Unless, of course, [we forgot to do that too.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304274/area-51-emails-dont-have-unsubscribe-link-anymore)

Comment: Thanks! I took the plunge and it seems to work...